# Ruby array initialize on read

Tags: ruby

I would like to be able to do this:

```
my_array = Array.new
my_array[12] += 1
```

In other words, somehow upon trying to access entry 12, finding it uninitialized, it is initialized to zero so I can add one to it. Array.new has a default: parameter, but that comes into play when you initialize the array with a known number of slots. Other than writing my own class, is there a ruby-ish way of doing this?

Comment: Can you use `my_array[12] ||= 1` ? This will initialize if array[12] is nil

Comment: Good lead but then I still have to increment it if was not nil

Comment: What's the size of the array? Is 11 the last element, and 12 the one just after that one? (If it's not the last you should do something with the ones inbetween)

Comment: Whole point is that the array length is not known

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
a[12] = (a[12] ||= 0) + 1
```

Comment: redundant assignment here, `a[12] = (a[12] || 0) + 1` works too.

Comment: @Coolness : Please don't

Comment: I like this best because its the most direct representation I was looking for, but the idea with a Hash is also excellent!

Answer (score 4):

No need to create a new class :

```
my_hash = Hash.new(0)
my_hash[12] += 1
p my_hash
#=> {12=>1}
```

For many cases, hashes and arrays can be used interchangeably.
An array with an arbitrary number of elements and a default value sounds like a hash to me ;)

Just to make it clear : `Hash` and `Array` aren't equivalent. There will be cases where using a hash instead of an array will be completely wrong.

Comment: I knew that Hash had that but it never occurred to me to use it instead of an array!

Comment: Unfortunately, this is plain wrong. Try `a = []; a[12] = 1; puts a` and you’ll see what I am saying.

Comment: @mudasobwa : without knowing more about the OP needs, it's too early to tell IMHO. My solution could be plain wrong, it could also work just fine. With your example, what exactly would be the problem, with which use case?

Comment: There are side effects of using `Array`, which are absent in case of using `Hash`. Side effects are the most hard-to-find evil-to-debug etc part of the code. This should be at least understood, taken into account and mentioned :)

Comment: “what exactly would be the problem”—setting `a[12]` in the array results in `a.count #⇒ 13`. In hash `count` will return guess what?

Comment: Sure. But I could argue that count=13 is wrong and that new elements shouldn't be just nil but zeroes. It once again depends on the OP motivations, which are still unknown. I'll add a note to my answer as soon as I have a decent keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Making use of `nil.to_i == 0`

```
my_array = Array.new
my_array[12] = my_array[12].to_i + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Note, that unlike other solutions here so far, this one works for any arbitrary initial value.

```
my_array = Array.new.extend(Module.new {
  def [] idx
    super || 0
  end
})
my_array[12] += 1
#⇒ 1
```

Comment: This should be how `new` works, but sadly it's not the case. Maybe subclassing Array into `ArrayWithDefault` is a better plan than a dynamic mixin. This could get punishingly expensive if a lot of these are created since each instance has its own pet module.

Comment: @tadman yes, this is true; I have just measured it, the penalty is the pet module is 20× slower. My intent was to show the approach, optimization is on the reader. In any case, the “proper” answer here was lazy initialization of the array member.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the stock `Array::new` method.

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-c-new

You will either need to monkey patch `Array` class, or monkey patch `nil` class. And they are not recommended.

If you have a specific use case, I would create a new wrapper class around `Array`

```
class MyArray < Array
  def [](i)
    super(i) ? super(i) : self[i] = 0
  end
end

arr = MyArray.new
arr[12] += 1 # => 1
```